React Native with using expo-web-browser on android shows two options with same package to redirect to app
I have some problem using expo-web-browser on android shows two options with same package to redirect to app. does anyone have the same problem? Heres my AndroidManifest file activity code.
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:exported="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="com.package.name"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>


Anyone can help?
And I have also tried

Creating new Activity so that Intent Filters are in added in 2 different Activities in Manifest
Added a WebView view instead of expo-web-browser to check if its a Library issue
Checked for Intent filters in Manifest file
Checked Updating MainActivity to check for Intent and directly redirecting
Added the screen to Navigation Container

